# Rails countdown characters - replace script tag in view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5 app I'm trying to display the amount of characters remaining for the following text area in the view with  tag:

```
<%= form_for @note, :url => registrant_notes_path(@registrant) do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.text_area :body, maxlength: 1000, style: 'width:100%;', id: "review_text" %>

    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var review_text = $("#review_text");
  var counter     = $("#counter");
  var max_length  = counter.data("maximum-length");

  counter.text(max_length - review_text.val().length);
  review_text.keyup(function() {
      counter.text(max_length - $(this).val().length);
  });

});
</script>
```

How to get rid of this script tag and move it to some js file? I created new file under `app/assets/javascripts/notes.js` with below code:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  var review_text = $("#review_text");
  var counter     = $("#counter");
  var max_length  = counter.data("maximum-length");

  counter.text(max_length - review_text.val().length);
  review_text.keyup(function() {
      counter.text(max_length - $(this).val().length);
  });

});
```

but then this JS code stops working - it stops counting down. Should I add this notes.js somewhere or am I missed something else?

Comment: Please check if you have this line `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` in your `views/layouts/application.html.rb`.  and something like this `//= require jquery //= require jquery_ujs //= require turbolinks //= require_tree .` in `assets/javascripts/manifest.js` or `assets/javascripts/application.js`.

Comment: @Abhinay I've got `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` the rest are also on site.

Comment: Actually, in rails 5 they have introduced a new place for javascript (app/javascript/) and your application.js should be present here. please make sure it has code like this: `require("@rails/ujs").start() require("turbolinks").start()...` and write your event listener in this file.

Comment: remove any javascript under `assets/javascripts/..`. In Rails 5 app, you must have `assets/config/manifest.js` where you link your assets. Remove any line which points to javascript in manifest.js. Then, add your event listener in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`. ex: `document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => `

Comment: make sure you have these two `require("@rails/ujs").start() require("turbolinks").start()` as the first things in `javascript/packs/application.js`

Comment: @Abhinay this app is very old and has been running for 5 years, everything you write is already on board. The issue is should I add my file somewhere? or should I write my function on a different way?

Comment: Assuming everything is already in place, you should write your code under `app/javascript/packs/notes.js` or simply write it in `app/javascript/packs/application.js` if this feature is shared in multiple places. You may have to require `require("notes")` in `application.js`